# ¿Cómo borrar un widget de una QGridLayout en Qt?

Tags: qt, gridview, layout, vistas, grid

Quiero hacer que aparezca o desaparezca un QRadioButton en una vista construida con QGridLayout dependiendo de una variable. He probado a usar la función [removeWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#removeWidget) (de dos maneras diferentes) de QGridLayout class, pero no me funciona, el grid no se va de la interfaz.

¿Cómo puedo borrarlo de la UI?

```
if (a==0) {
    p_theGrid->addWidget(radio1, 6, 0);
    p_theGrid->update();
} else if (a==1) {
    //p_theGrid->removeWidget(p_theGrid->itemAtPosition(6,0)->widget());
    p_theGrid->removeWidget(radio1);
    p_theGrid->update();
}
```

Aquí adjunto el código completo del `MainWindow.cpp`. La parte de código dónde tengo el problema se encuentra indicada (está al final).

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "Model_Sqlite.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    qDebug()<<"beginning";
    p_theModel= new Model_Sqlite(this);
    // Grid
    QWidget *p_theCentralWidget=new QWidget(this);

    p_theGrid=new QGridLayout(p_theCentralWidget);

    // table view
    QTableView *p_theView=new QTableView(this);
    p_theView->setModel(p_theModel);

    // button new table
    p_createNewTable=new QPushButton("Create table",this);
    connect(p_createNewTable,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(createNewTable()));

    //button insert data
    p_insertNewData=new QPushButton("Insert data", this);
    connect(p_insertNewData,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(insertNewData()));

    /*==================================================*/
    QPushButton *p_myTrein=new QPushButton(this);
    p_myTrein->setCheckable(true);
    p_myTrein->setGeometry(QRect(500, 30, 211, 131));
    QIcon icon2;
    icon2.addFile(QString::fromUtf8("C:/Users/72496/Documents/Maria/PruebasSQLite/QtSQLChinook/Tren.png"), QSize(), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::On);
    p_myTrein->setIcon(icon2);
    p_myTrein->setIconSize(QSize(100, 100));
    /*===================================================*/
    //button delete data
    p_deleteDataRowId=new QPushButton("Delete data",this);
    connect(p_deleteDataRowId,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(deleteDataFromId()));

    // name edit
    QLabel *p_labelName = new QLabel("Name", this);
    p_editName = new QLineEdit(this);
    // Make buddy
    p_labelName->setBuddy(p_editName);

    // delete data id edit
    QLabel *p_labelDeleteId=new QLabel("Delete data Id",this);
    p_editDeleteId=new QSpinBox(this);
    p_editDeleteId->setRange(0, 100);
    p_editDeleteId->setSingleStep(1);
    p_editDeleteId->setValue(0);
    // Make buddy
    p_labelDeleteId->setBuddy(p_editDeleteId);

    // Check Box
    checkBox1 = new QCheckBox("My CheckBox");
    connect(checkBox1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(seeIfChecked()));

    // Radio Button
    radio1 = new QRadioButton("Select View 1 - MyQtTable");
    connect(radio1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(seeIfChecked()));

    radio2 = new QRadioButton("Select View 2 - Tracks");
    connect(radio2,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(seeIfChecked()));

    QSplitter *p_theSplitter=new QSplitter(this);

    p_theSplitter->addWidget(p_theView);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(p_theSplitter,0,2,10,1);
    //p_theGrid->addWidget(p_theView,0,2,10,1);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(p_createNewTable,0,0);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(p_insertNewData,1,0);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(p_deleteDataRowId,2,0);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(p_labelName,3,0);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(p_editName, 3, 1);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(p_labelDeleteId,4,0);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(p_editDeleteId,4,1);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(checkBox1,5,0);

    /*===================================================*/
    p_theGrid->addWidget(p_myTrein,10,0);

    //    if (a==1){
    //        p_theGrid->addWidget(radio1,6,0);
    //    }else if (a==0){
    //        p_theGrid->addWidget(radio2,7,0);
    //    }
    /*====================================================*/

    //    p_theGrid->addWidget(radio1,6,0);
    //    p_theGrid->addWidget(radio2,7,0);
    setCentralWidget(p_theCentralWidget);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    qDebug()<<"the end";
}

void MainWindow::createNewTable()
{
    qDebug()<<"Creating table begin...";
    p_theModel->AddTableToDatabase();
}

void MainWindow::insertNewData()
{
    qDebug()<<"Insertion begin...";
    QString textName=p_editName->text();
    p_theModel->InsertData(textName);
}

void MainWindow::deleteDataFromId()
{
    qDebug()<<"Deleting process begin...";
    int theId=p_editDeleteId->value();
    p_theModel->DeleteRowID(theId);
}

void MainWindow::seeIfChecked()
{
    // bool checkBoxState=false;
    bool radioOneState=false;
    bool radioTwoState=false;
    int selectedViewModel=0;

    if (checkBox1->isChecked()){
        qDebug()<<"CHECKABLE BUTTON IS CHECKED";
        a=0;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"CHECKABLE BUTTON IS NOT CHECKED";
        a=1;
    }

    if (radio1->isChecked()){
        qDebug()<<"RADIO BUTTON IS CHECKED";
        radioOneState=true;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"RADIO BUTTON IS NOT CHECKED";
        radioOneState=false;
    }

    if (radio2->isChecked()){
        qDebug()<<"RADIO BUTTON 2 IS CHECKED";
        radioTwoState=true;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"RADIO BUTTON 2 IS NOT CHECKED";
        radioTwoState=false;
    }
    qDebug()<<radioOneState;
    qDebug()<<radioTwoState;

    if (radioOneState==true && radioTwoState==false)
    {
        selectedViewModel=1;
        p_theModel->chooseView(selectedViewModel);
    }
    else if(radioOneState==false && radioTwoState==true)
    {
        selectedViewModel=2;
        p_theModel->chooseView(selectedViewModel);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"No posible view";
    }

    // AQUÍ SE ENCUENTRA LA PARTE DE CÓDIGO DONDE TENGO EL PROBLEMA

    if (a==0){
        p_theGrid->addWidget(radio1,6,0);
        // p_theGrid->removeWidget(radio2);
        p_theGrid->update();

    }else if (a==1){

        //p_theGrid->removeWidget(p_theGrid->itemAtPosition(6,0)->widget());
        p_theGrid->removeWidget(radio1);

        //p_theGrid->addWidget(radio2,7,0);
        p_theGrid->update();

    }

}
```

Aquí dejo una captura de la aplicación. Lo que quiero obtener es que cuando el botón `My CheckBox`, llamado 'checkBox1' en el código, esté seleccionado el `QRadioButton`, llamado `radio1`en el código y `Select View 1- MyQtTable` en la interfaz, aparezca. Y que sin embargo, cuando `My CheckBox`no este seleccionado, el `QRadioButton`desaparezca.

He comprobado que a la condición del `if (a==0)` y `if(a==1)` entra correctamente cuando `My CheckBox esta con tic y sin tic.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Desde que ámbito estás accediendo al `QRadioButton`?
Si estás en `MainWindow` tienes acceso a `ui`, prueba a modificar la linea `p_theGrid->removeWidget(radio1);`

Comment: Accedo desde QMainWindow al QRadioButton. Tengo mi layout construido en la QMainWindow también, no he usado el diseñador de `ui`.  Qué modificación me sugieres para la línea de código `p_theGrid->removeWidget(radio1)`?

Comment: ¿Puedes editar la pregunta y añadir el código completo para poder tener una visión mas general del problema?

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta. Solo he añadido el .cpp puesto que es ahí donde tengo el problema, concretamente en la parte final del código. También he añadido una captura del programa, para que se vea más fácil.

Comment: Estas eliminando el `QRadioButton` del `QGridLayout` aunque no parezca, se sigue visualizando porque no ha sido eliminado del `QWidget *p_theCentralWidget` que es el padre.
Si no lo he entendido mal, quieres mostrar `radio1` o `radio2` en función de `checkBox1`, con lo cual te recomiendo añadir los dos en el `p_theGrid` al construir todo en el `MainWindow`, y en función de `checkBox1` usar `radio1->setVisible(false/true);` y `radio2->setVisible(false/true);` respectivamente dentro de la condición de 'a'.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. He probado con `setVisibl` y el resultado que obtengo cumple mi objetivo. Gracias!!

Comment: Perfecto, ¿Puedes editar la pregunta para añadir como ha quedado resuelta?

Comment: Ahora mismo me respondo la pregunta y así saldrá como respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `QRadioButton`no se eliminaba porque al eliminarlo con `p_theGrid->removeWidget(radio1)` del `QGridLayout` no estaba siendo eliminado del `QWidget *p_theCentralWidget` que es el padre.

Por ello he optado por la opción de implementar desde un inicio el `QRadioButton` el `QGridLayout`pero dejándolo como no visible con la sentencia `radio1->setVisible(false)`.  Esta es la parte del código donde defino el botón, lo dejo como no visible y lo añado a mi layout:

```
// Radio Button
    radio1 = new QRadioButton("Select View 1 - MyQtTable");

    radio2 = new QRadioButton("Select View 2 - Tracks");

    radio1->setVisible(false);
    radio2->setVisible(false);

    QSplitter *p_theSplitter=new QSplitter(this);

    p_theSplitter->addWidget(p_theView);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(p_theSplitter,0,2,10,1);
    //p_theGrid->addWidget(p_theView,0,2,10,1);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(p_createNewTable,0,0);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(p_insertNewData,1,0);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(p_deleteDataRowId,2,0);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(p_labelName,3,0);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(p_editName, 3, 1);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(p_labelDeleteId,4,0);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(p_editDeleteId,4,1);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(checkBox1,5,0);
    // AÑADO MI RADIO BUTTON, radio1,  AL p_theGrid
    p_theGrid->addWidget(radio1,6,0);
    p_theGrid->addWidget(radio2,7,0);
    setCentralWidget(p_theCentralWidget);
```

Y tras ello, en la condición de mirar si el `QCheckBox`, llamado `checkBox1`está clickado o no, dependiendo del resultado lo hago visible o no, de la siguiente forma:

```
void MainWindow::seeIfChecked()
{

    if (checkBox1->isChecked()){
        qDebug()<<"CHECKABLE BUTTON IS CHECKED";
        a=0;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"CHECKABLE BUTTON IS NOT CHECKED";
        a=1;
    }

    // DEPENDIENDO DEL RESULTADO PONGO EL QRADIOBUTTON VISIBLE O NO

    if (a==0){
        radio1->setVisible(true);
        radio2->setVisible(false);

        //p_theGrid->update();
        qDebug()<<"Añado widget";

    }else if (a==1){
        radio1->setVisible(false);
        radio2->setVisible(true);

        qDebug()<<"Quito Widget";

    }
```